# Block extensions from being installed in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, windows-vista, security, google-chrome-extensions

#### System Information

OS: Windows Vista Home Premium

User: Standard User

#### Objective

Stop the `Standard User` from installing **any** extensions in Google Chrome. There is one currently installed for AVG that I'm okay with, but that's it.

#### Tactics Researched

I found some stuff online that mentioned some black and white lists, surrounding some registry entries, but when I tried to find the entries they didn't exist. This isn't terribly surprising, I'm guessing I'll need to create them. But this is really not an ideal solution.

I also see some stuff surrounding GPO Policies, but that doesn't work for me because this is just a personal computer.

---

Hopefully somebody can help!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just disable write access for the extensions folder to that specific user. Extensions folder can be found in this path.

> %LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions

To disable write access, go to properties > security > edit

[image]
Select the user, hit Deny and they will not be able to install extensions, please check and verify !

Comment: With this method, extensions that are installed will not update, right? Also will they be functional?